# How to get the all prior field value in textearea field or formula field

Tags: formula-field

I have one text field like priority and I will change every day the priority. now I would like to store the prior values in the text area field or formula field. how to do?

Temporary i am viewing the activity track history. so how to display all prior value(all last changed) in the formula text field.

Answer (score 2):

Field History tracking is the right way to track field value changes. especially if you are changing the priority field value everyday. (you can never be sure about the text lenght you need to store the entire history)

but if you still need to get all the previous values in a field, you can try the below

1. Create a Custom Long Text Area field in your object (say its name is PriorityHistory__c)
2. Create a New Workflow Rule on your custom object
3. Select rule criteria as formula evaluates to true and use a formula
   like
   **ISCHANGED(YourPriorityField)**
4. Select workflow action as field update and select the custom field
   PriorityHistory__c as the field to be updated
5. enter the new value as a formula

   **PriorityHistory__c & '-' & PRIORVALUE(YourPriorityField)**

Comment: the field update can even datestamp each entry and you can put BR() after each entry so it looks like a proper log. Note in V31, you can have long text fields of 128K but at some point, you'll blow up the field and stop the logging

Comment: This is a great way to keep basic history without blowing up data storage. Another drawback is that you can't run a report on this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger and make a string variable .
each priority value concatenate  with previous value and update in text area field .