# Custom field to track field history as a log

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, workflow, history-tracking

I have a requirement where field history of custom field Account_Update__c should be tracked as a log in an another custom field called Account_Update_Timeline__c which is a long text field.

I'm aware that we can do it OOB using object's field history tracking but I want to display the log on record detail page as a field.

Now, I found this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/how-to-get-the-all-prior-field-value-in-textearea-field-or-formula-field) where it was suggested to use WF Rule to track the field value changes but i could only display last changed value instead of all the values as a log. I mean it should be as follows

```
datetime - oldvalue1
datetime - oldvalue2
datetime - oldvalue3
```

Do i need to make any changes to WF Rule here to display all the changes one after other or is there any better approach. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all the historical changes, basically you just need to keep adding the updated timeline to the field `Account_Update_Timeline__c`.

In your Workflow, use the Field Update action to set the field value:

```
Account_Update_Timeline__c &
IF(NOT ISBLANK(Account_Update_Timeline__c), BR(), '') & /* Don't add new line for 1st line */
TEXT(NOW()) + ' - ' + Account_Update__c
```

Comment: Thanks @Hengky :)